# Visual Studio forcing ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value

Tags: visual-studio-2019, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to use the Package Manager Console with EF Core 2.2 in Visual Studio 2019 to run an `Update-Database` command. I am targeting a specific database in my code by changing the connection string based on the value of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT.
The code achieves this by using

```
public Startup(IHostinEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        // set EF Core Dev connection string here
    }
}
```

In the project properties Debug panel, I have the value set to "Development" and since the Package Manager Cosole ignores that and uses the Environment variable, I have typed

> PM> $Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"

I then verify it set correctly by typing

> PM> $Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

And it correctly returns *Development*.

But the problem is if I then run

> PM> Get-DbContext

It targets my production database instead of development, and indeed, when typing $Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT again, it yields *Production*!

There is nothing in my code that would change this value on the fly.
Even more confusing is the fact I have taken exactly these steps in the past with no problem.

Any troubleshooting ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the unsatisfying conclusion that merely restarting Visual Studio 2019 corrected the issue. I'm guessing there is some sort of bug in it or the PM Console.

Just for reference, the version I am using is 16.6.3 on Windows 10 Pro.
Package Manager Host 5.6.0.6591